# Excel VBA: Set new external data connection and refresh without querying user

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have an excel workbook that has an external data connection to a .txt file. This is in the form of a QueryTable.

What I'm trying to do is create a dialog box to ask the user for a folder of .txt files. I would then loop through those files, refreshing the query table with each new file. After the initial folder dialog, I don't want the user to see any other dialogs.

My current code is:

```
myQuery = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).QueryTables(1)
Filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select files")

For Each Filename In Filenames
    myQuery.Connection = "TEXT;" & Filename
    myQuery.Refresh 'This displays a dialog box to choose a new file each time.
    ' Some other code that would execute after each refresh
Loop
```

What I'm looking for is something that will refresh the QueryTable with the current .Connection string, but will not open a new dialog on each refresh.

I've tried using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, but that does not suppress the Refresh dialog.

Any ideas to accomplish something similar would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaRoss, that's exactly the property that I was looking for and overlooked apparently. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it resolved?

Comment: No problem!  I can't count how many times I've missed a property or method I needed and all it takes is another set of eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `.TextFilePromptOnRefresh` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197205.aspx) of the QueryTable to `False`.